# Continuous trading economies

Tags: continuous-time, trading

*Continuous trading economies.* I see this expression in many papers but I do not know what it means in the precise technical sense. And I'm not an economist.

Maybe it could refer to an economic environment in which agents are allowed to trade continuously. But in what way? In time and goods to trades? E.g., in time: there is a subset $S\subset \mathbb R$ s.t. $t\in S$? Or, in goods: there is a subset $U\subset \mathbb R$ that represents all the possible goods that agents of this economy can trade?

Comment: Could you point to an example of where this is used?